# Create consecutive tables in jaspersoft

Tags: jasper-reports

[image]

I am using JasperReports and I cannot find the way to create consecutive tables. When the first one is filled in, the next one will cover it instead of being shifted.

Did anyone face this problem before?

**UPDATE**

I am using the subreport with two detail bands and one table into each of the detail bands.

So far I generate the page for the parent report but the subreport area is blank.

This is the code where I interact with the reports:

```
try {

    HashMap param = new HashMap();

    JRBeanCollectionDataSource tableA = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(tableAItems);
    param.put("AtableDatasource", tableA);
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource tableB = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(tableBItems);
    param.put("BtableDatasource", tableB);
    param.put("tableHeadA","TABLE A HEADER");
    param.put("column1AHead","A COL 1");
    param.put("column2AHead","A COL 2");
    param.put("column3AHead","A COL 3");
    param.put("header","SAMPLE REPORT");
    param.put("theDetails", "THE DETAILS");
    param.put("detail1Label", "DETAIL BAND 1");
    param.put("detail2Label", "DETAIL BAND 2");

    InputStream parent = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/sample_parent.jasper");
    JasperPrint jpParent = JasperFillManager.fillReport(parent, param, new JREmptyDataSource(1));

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jpParent, "C:\\REPORTS\\sampleReport.pdf");


} catch (JRException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As usual, the sample code is uploaded to the GitHub repo linked below.

GitHub repo: https://github.com/MichaelKnight/jaspertest.git

Comment: Attached you can find the pic and I linked the repository with the report

Comment: You actual have a table c (to the right), are you sure that table A ends where you have indicated?, do you want table B after both table A and table  C?...

Comment: I wanna get the table B below the A, another table will be below the table C (considering C the one on the right of A)

Comment: @PetterFriberg I am completely sure. The point is, both tables are dynamically filled in. So the the Table A will end at that point in this case, in a different one could be longer or shorter. My idea was to make the table B automatically relocated below. Is this possible? any procedure to follow?

Comment: Try to set positionType="Float" on the frame containing your table

Comment: However with also another table under table c, I'm not sure that jasper report manage to create the layout that you like when filling vertically, I would have designed it with 2 subreport (1 for table A,B and 1 for table C,D) next to each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101571/discussion-between-michael-knight-and-petter-friberg).

Comment: I already used in one test the subreports but I didn't get the expected resutls. Again, overlapped tables.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I will test it within a couple of days and I will let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that the frame containing the `jr:table` does not have `positionType="float"`, you have set it to the `jr:table` but you **need to set it to frame**).

However to better control and achieve your desired layout (since you have tables to the right), consider to create 2 subreport.

Pass to subreport `new JREmptyDataSource(1)` as datasource to generate 1 record detail band and your parameter map, to get parameter `$P{B3questionsDatasource}` etc. in your subreport.

1. **subreport**, containing the table A,B in image, either put them on below each other or use multiple detail band's

   ```
   <detail>
     <band height="50">
         ... table 1 ....
     </band>
     <band height="50">
         ... table 2 ....
     </band>
   </detail>
   ```
2. **sub report**, with table C and new table D (as in example above).

In **main report** included the subreport's on next to each other.

Example

```
<subreport>
   <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="400" height="20" uuid="a7a89ebb-54d4-4b6e-8c9f-c107e8a40bbb"/>
    <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Comment: I am testing your new approach that looks quite promising but I am facing some issues. You can find the details in the first post.

Comment: @MichaelKnight, first there is no need to compile the report of you have the design, the sequence is (compile jrxml if need) , get design, fillreport. so just pass the design to fillmanager

Comment: @MichaelKnight, you are filling the subreport by itself its not included in main report (an called from this)... you can do this and then merge them during export.... you like to continue, like this... I can update answer (in current answer it is included in main report, hence you just call 1 report)

Comment: @Peter Friberg I modified my code in order to make a single call to the parent report, what makes sense. However I still get the empty PDF output. I dunno if maybe it is related to this message I get on the console when I execute the application:

`feb 03, 2016 12:29:23 PM net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter <init>
ADVERTENCIA: The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null.`

Comment: @MichaelKnight If you have no query in report this is not a problem... I can't find the sample.jrxml you are mentioning in code.

Comment: @Peter Friberg, I got it now. I uploaded the changes to the GitHub repo for further reference if any other has the same issue as me. Thanks a lot for your advice and support.